# vim bug?! random character "ghosting" and ruler in the middle of the text with :set columns on

Tags: vim

This is super strange and preventing me from writing because it's super bothersome. As I write weird characters appear if I have columns= on. First thing that will appear (and all of these issues are after the 1st line) is the ruler or gutter (at least thats the only two things with that background color) appear in the middle of the text. Secondly, extra characters will appear at the end of the line. For example:

```
Here is some text
here is the wrap, this is still part of the first line
```

The actual output would be

```
Here is some textt
here is the wrap, this is still part of the first line
```

And if I go to delete all the text I'll be left with

```
                 t
                                                     e
```

Or something. Here's a video where I caught some of the issues:

http://screencast.com/t/QsjZ0b2jG6bh

Again, this is *only* with set `columns=80` on. Also, here is what is in my vimrc file that also changes in this `:Write` mode I made.

```
func! WordProcessorMode()
  setlocal formatoptions=1
  setlocal noexpandtab
  setlocal spell spelllang=en_us
  set complete+=s
  set formatprg=par
  setlocal wrap
  setlocal linebreak
  let g:solarized_termcolors=256
  set background=light
  colorscheme solarized
  colors solarized
  set nocul
  set columns=80
  set noruler
  AutoCloseOff
endfu
com! Write call WordProcessorMode()
```

Comment: What terminal do you use, and what is the value of `$TERM`? Looks like a mismatch or term database corruption to me, not a bug in Vim.

Comment: Why `set columns=80`?

Comment: @romainl so the words wrap and the text doesn't flow across the screen. It's hard to read 50 words a line :)

Comment: @IngoKarkat I use iTerm and echoing `$TERM` prints `xterm-256color`

Comment: You want `set textwidth=80`. See `:h 'textwidth'`.

Comment: @romainl Nope, doesn't work at all. Just changed column to textwidth and get this. The ruler is set to 80. Notice that it keeps going: http://f.cl.ly/items/3Z3f351p0a2N3b2x2m13/Screen%20Shot%202013-04-27%20at%208.05.27%20PM.png

Comment: It wasn't mean to solve your problem, it was meant to correct your misuse of `columns`. I have no idea what your problem is. Does it happen with `$ vim -n NONE --noplugin`?

Comment: @romainl I never said it was meant to fix my bug :) I was saying textwidth makes the text flow past 80 characters and wrap when the words hit the window's edge. columns=80 forces the text to wrap no matter how big my window is set to. textwidth doesn't do anything for me really.

Comment: @romainl, nope. My problems still happen with no plugins turned on. Only thing that fixes *most* of the issues is turning on nolist. But, even that doesn't fix all of the rendering issues.

Comment: No. `textwidth` is *the* canonical way to prevent your text from ever going past column 80 when you type and it has been so for dozens of years. You tried without plugins but did you try with no vimrc?

Comment: If I remove the vimrc then, yes, my problem goes away, but that's because my Write function doesn't exist. When I run that is when it happens :( also, with textwidth, if I remove everything and set it during a vim session it wraps, but it seems to literally create breaks, not actually wrap.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem and it's really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I had the same issue.  I am using iTerm2, with zsh + tmux on Mac OS 10.8.1.  I fixed it by removing the "set wrap" option, and setting the "set nowrap" option.

Yes, it's not a true solution since we have to disable wrap, but at least I can work in vim now.

Hope that helps.